# How to disregard the NaN data point in numpy array and generate the normalized data in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

Say I have a numpy array that has some float('nan'), I don't want to impute those data now and I want to first normalize those and keep the NaN data at the original space, is there any way I can do that?

Previously I used `normalize` function in `sklearn.Preprocessing`, but that function seems can't take any NaN contained array as input.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to normalize an array with NaNs in it and ignore the NaNs ?

Comment: I want to ignore the NaNs

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can mask your array using the `numpy.ma.array` function and subsequently apply any `numpy` operation:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10)            # Generate random data.
a = np.where(a > 0.8, np.nan, a)  # Set all data larger than 0.8 to NaN

a = np.ma.array(a, mask=np.isnan(a)) # Use a mask to mark the NaNs

a_norm  = a / np.sum(a) # The sum function ignores the masked values.
a_norm2 = a / np.std(a) # The std function ignores the masked values.
```

You can still access your raw data:

```
print a.data
```

Comment: Great, and then how can I recover back the NaN values?

Comment: What do you mean with recover back?

Comment: I want to put back those NaN values in the array.

Comment: They will remain there. The `numpy` operations just skip the NaN values.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`numpy.nansum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) to compute the norm and ignore nan:

```
In [54]: x
Out[54]: array([  1.,   2.,  nan,   3.])
```

Here's the norm with `nan` ignored:

```
In [55]: np.sqrt(np.nansum(np.square(x)))
Out[55]: 3.7416573867739413
```

`y` is the normalized array:

```
In [56]: y = x / np.sqrt(np.nansum(np.square(x)))

In [57]: y
Out[57]: array([ 0.26726124,  0.53452248,         nan,  0.80178373])

In [58]: np.linalg.norm(y[~np.isnan(y)])
Out[58]: 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `nansum` and `np.ma.array` answers are good options, however, those functions are not as commonly used or explicit (IMHO) as the following:

```py
import numpy as np
def rms(arr):
    arr = np.array(arr) # Sanitize the input
    np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(arr[np.isfinite(arr)]))) #root-mean-square

print(rms([np.nan,-1,0,1]))
```