# How to get numpy einsum to ignore nan's?

Tags: python, numpy, nan, numpy-einsum

Let's say you use einsum to calculate the slope and intercept in a simple regression as follows:

```
slope = (np.einsum('ij,ij->i', y_norm, x_norm) /
           np.einsum('ij,ij->i', x_norm, x_norm))
intercept = y_mean[:, 0] - slope * x_mean[:, 0]
```

where y_norm and x_norm are *m x n* matrices (numpy arrays) with *m* standardised variables and *n* observations.

You now use an algorithm that trims outliers and changes them to nan values in the matrix of *x* and *y* variables. This gives the *y_trimmed* and *x_trimmed* matrix and after standardising *y_trimmed_norm* and *x_trimmed_norm*.

You then rerun the einsum lines of code to obtain the trimmed slope and trimmed intercept values.

```
slope_trimmed = (np.einsum('ij,ij->i', y_trimmed_norm, x_trimmed_norm) /
                       np.einsum('ij,ij->i', x_trimmed_norm, x_trimmed_norm))
intercept_trimmed = y_trimmed_mean[:, 0] - beta_trimmed * x_trimmed_mean[:, 0]
```

However, this results in the output:

```
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
       nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

How does one get einsum to ignore the nan's in the numpy arrays?

Comment: Maybe this thread could be similar to your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37750034/5401481

Comment: I think I got it to work with that suggestion, using np.ma.array to determine x_trimmed and y_trimmed. After that, the code worked with einsum. Thank you :)

Comment: Code runs with `einsum` but I don't think it is ignoring the trimmed values.

Comment: Provide a [mcve], with sample arrays, and expected result.  Note your use of `einsum` just multiplies the arrays and sums on the 2nd axis.  `(y_norm * x_norm).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: try `np.nansum(A1*A2, axis=1)`